# When are knex.js queries "promises" executed/resolved?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, knex.js

With normal promises a promise will resolve as soon as it is able to do so, once the current code has halted. Consider the following pseudo code:

```
const p = SomePromiseDoingLoad();
calculatethings();
await sleepPromise();
//during sleep the promise p might/will have resolved already.
await p; //awaiting just makes *sure* the promise is already executed
```

However how does this translate to a query builder like knex? There seems to be no way to prevent a promise from executing?

```
const p = knex.select('*').from('table');
//p could be executed now already.
const data = await gatherDataFromWebsite();
//p most probably will have resolved??
p.limit(data.limit) // ???
```

What would happen in above, and further how do I even *prevent* this from potentially happening? Node is afterall always allowed to resolved the promise as soon as it can, so just chaining dots could let it resolve?

```
const p = knex.select('*').from('table').limit(5); 
let q = knex.select('*');
q = q.from('table');
q = q.limit(5);
```

Or what magic trickery is knex doing behind the schemes to postpone execution?

Comment: if you think it's an attack then I apologise - I'll remove it - perhaps you should realise you aren't the only one who may use the wrong word or words at times

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Knex query builder is not a Promise, but something that Promise/A+ spec calls `thenable`.

Knex only executes network I/O when you call `.then()` on a query builder object. As long as you have not called `.then()` on a query builder object it will simply chain and return a query builder object instead of a Promise.

The `await` keyword resolves the query builder and internally calls a its `.then()` method therefore using `await` with a `knex` query builder object will also cause it to return a promise.

It is not postponing execution. Instead execution is triggered by the query builder object's (not Promise) `.then()` method.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that knex' query object do not follow the Promise/A+ specification? Wouldn't this mean that `promise.all([firstquery, secondquery])` means that the queries are not called parallel?

Comment: It's a query object. Not a Promise. It only needs to follow knex's own specification

Comment: Note that `Promise.all()`, like `await`, calls a thing's internal `.then()` method thus will accidentally/coincidentally convert kenx query object into promises. Depending on your database server configuration the queries may be parallel or queued in the database but javascript will execute both concurrently (not sequentially) because `Promise.all()` will not wait for one to complete before calling the other

Comment: Note that part of Promise/A+ specification is not checking if an object is actually a Promise but just that it has the required methods (namely `.then()` and maybe `.catch()` if there is an error). It was specified that way for compatibility between promise libraries

Comment: @slebetman Promises/A+ doesn't specific `catch`. It specifies the second parameter of `then`.

Comment: @paul23 Knex query builder is something that Promise/A+ spec calls `thenable`. So yeah knex follows that spec. For example here https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1952 is some discussion about it. There has been lots of confusion about Promises and thenables during the years in knex issues.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö reviewing this older question I realize that the text you gave was vital for my understanding. I did not really grasp the difference between thenable and a promise  before your comment. And your comment made me understand the answer. Should the answer be updated to include this?

Comment: @paul23 I sent an edit 