# How to write a chain of methods in JS with a mapping function

Tags: javascript, arrays, knex.js

## Context

I'm using knex.js, a SQL query builder. This question is not specific about knex.js though but about javascript semantics, so knex.js is just here to illustrate my problem. So I build SQL queries with knex.js by just chaining methods.

For instance, to get contacts in a table:

```js
const getContacts = await knex
  .select('*')
  .from('contacts')
  .where({age: 21}) // Filters contacts that have age 21
  .andWhere({name: 'Bob'}) // Filters contacts that are named Bob
  .andWhere({eyeColor: 'blue'}) // ...you got the idea
  ...
```

## Question

I want to make a function that given an array of filters, returns the built query to get the right set of contacts. I can theoretically put as many `.andWhere` that I want so I'd like do declare that with a map over the input array or something like that, i.e

```js
const getContactsQuery = (filterArray) => (
  knex
    .select('*')
    .from('contacts')
    .where(filterArray[0])
    .andWhere(filterArray[1])
    ...
    .andWhere(filterArray[filterArray.length - 1])
)
```

**The question: Is there any way I can build this chain of `.andWhere` mapping over `filterArray`?**

## Things I've tried

### Using reduce this way

```js
const getContactsQuery = (filterArray) => (
  filterArray.reduce((acc, filterElement, index) => {
    if(index === 0) {
      return acc.where(filterElement)
    }
    return acc.andWhere(filterElement)
  },
  knex.select('*').from('contacts')
  )
)
```

This may not work because this would get knex to fetch the table elements at each iteration of the reduce.

**EDIT:** It should actually work for knex because "*knex does not query the database unless you await the last chaining*". So this is solved for my context but there eventually could be other use cases where this would not work, don't know ‍♂️

Comment: Do you want the mapping function to concatenate the `andWhere` instead of execute them?

Comment: @Csharls yes that's right

Comment: "*this would get knex to fetch the table elements at each iteration of the reduce.*" - what makes you think that? It should work as is, `reduce` is the proper solution here. Did you really try it?

Comment: knex does not query the database unless you await the last chaining. It does so by having its own `then` function. And since `async/await` is just syntaxic sugar for promises, you can definitely have your version work.

Comment: Yes, it actually does work but I thought not because I wasn't aware of that behaviour of knex. Thanks for the clarification 

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that would work for you?

```
const getContactsQuery = async (filterArray) => {
    const query = knex
      .select('*')
      .from('contacts');

    filterArray.forEach((filter,i) => {
        if(i==0)
            query.where(filter)
        else
            query.andWhere(filter)
    })
    
    return await query
}
```

For the semantics of when a knex query is actually executed, there is a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57758854/3134549

Of course if you don't want the query to be executed at the end of the function call, mark it as non-async and return the unawaited query.

Comment: I think `query.where` would need to be assigned to `query` but other than that it looks good. Thanks for the link, it clarifies and actually proves that solution as well as the reduce option right 

Comment: Any knex function call should just return the `QueryBuilder` you are currently operating on (thus you are able to chain functions continously), but since you're working on a reference anyway there is no reason to repeatedly write `query=query.operation(param)`

Answer (score 0):

If all of the filters requires an AND boolean operator, you can pass an object with multiple key->value, and knex will construct the query with AND.

For example:

```js
const getContactsQuery = (filterObj) => {
  return knex.select('*')
             .from('contacts')
             .where(filterObj);
};

const results = await getContactsQuery({
  col1: 'val1',
  col2: 'val2',
  col3: 'val3',
});
```